# Named Color in user defined property border color UIButton app crash

Tags: ios, crash, uibutton, ios11, xcode12

I have observed a wired behaviour in Xcode 12

My app crashes when I run the app on ios 11 or 12 simulator through Xcode 12.
I have set `borderColor` property of UIButton under user defined property in .xib file and I am assigning namedColor here. App is working fine when run through Xcode 11 or I if I assign a system provided color instead of namedColor. Has anything changed in Xcode 12 which is causing this crash?

`*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSUnknownKeyException', reason: '[<UIButton 0x7f8aea05xxxx> setValue:forUndefinedKey:]: this class is not key value coding-compliant for the key borderColor.'`

Comment: This answer might helps.
https://stackoverflow.com/a/55924143/2269789

Comment: enadun Thanks for responding but I have this property in xib, I haven't declared it in any of the class. SO cant mark it as @objc